# Need Help Parsing JSON with Swift using Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, parsing, alamofire

I'm trying to retrieve an article from Google news and parse it using Swift. I'm using Alamofire. I know the basics of what to when parsing, but the output seems kind of complex and I don't know how to access the "title" value. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Here is the JSON Output:**

```
responseData =     {
        cursor =         {
            currentPageIndex = 0;
            estimatedResultCount = 445755633;
            moreResultsUrl = "http://news.google.com/nwshp?oe=utf8&ie=utf8&source=uds&q=sports&hl=en&start=0";
            pages =             (
                                {
                    label = 1;
                    start = 0;
                },
                                {
                    label = 2;
                    start = 1;
                },
                                {
                    label = 3;
                    start = 2;
                },
                                {
                    label = 4;
                    start = 3;
                },
                                {
                    label = 5;
                    start = 4;
                },
                                {
                    label = 6;
                    start = 5;
                },
                                {
                    label = 7;
                    start = 6;
                },
                                {
                    label = 8;
                    start = 7;
                }
            );
        };
        results =         (
                        {
                GsearchResultClass = GnewsSearch;
                clusterUrl = "http://news.google.com/news/story?ncl=dO-ivvqeXteuGKMAkRap55WyAkOvM&hl=en&ned=us";
                content = "sportsbook The Third Circuit Court of Appeals will rehear a potentially landmark case Wednesday brought by the NCAA, NFL, MLB, NBA and NHL claiming a New Jersey gambling law enacted in 2014 that repealed certain prohibitions on sports wagering in ...";
                image =                 {
                    originalContextUrl = "http://lawnewz.com/sports/new-jersey-lawsuit-could-make-sports-betting-legal-across-the-country/";
                    publisher = LawNewz;
                    tbHeight = 53;
                    tbUrl = "http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ2htg8w11Y6_4ClDD80jdQN6VtGGMya5KomCyLCgzVjOsyMJLVdkffcSg9";
                    tbWidth = 80;
                    url = "http://lawnewz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/800px-Las_Vegas_sportsbook-351x234.jpg";
                };
                language = en;
                location = "";
                publishedDate = "Tue, 16 Feb 2016 10:47:00 -0800";
                publisher = LawNewz;
                relatedStories =                 (
                                        {
                        language = en;
                        location = "";
                        publishedDate = "Tue, 16 Feb 2016 07:34:35 -0800";
                        publisher = ESPN;
                        signedRedirectUrl = "http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=T&ct2=us&fd=S&url=http://espn.go.com/chalk/story/_/id/14785562/chalk-previewing-latest-new-jersey-sports-betting-appeal&cid=52779048299261&ei=5OHDVujuMfOmwQHOn53oAg&usg=AFQjCNH7bfL6cWr1Q8PKgPOkQIP7ZRUoRw";
                        title = "Future of sports betting once again at stake in New Jersey";
                        titleNoFormatting = "Future of sports betting once again at stake in New Jersey";
                        unescapedUrl = "http://espn.go.com/chalk/story/_/id/14785562/chalk-previewing-latest-new-jersey-sports-betting-appeal";
                        url = "http%3A%2F%2Fespn.go.com%2Fchalk%2Fstory%2F_%2Fid%2F14785562%2Fchalk-previewing-latest-new-jersey-sports-betting-appeal";
                    }
                );
                signedRedirectUrl = "http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=T&ct2=us&fd=S&url=http://lawnewz.com/sports/new-jersey-lawsuit-could-make-sports-betting-legal-across-the-country/&cid=52779048299261&ei=5OHDVujuMfOmwQHOn53oAg&usg=AFQjCNHAqRF8uPjG1Ki7yxjz0sATv05i6A";
                title = "New Jersey Lawsuit Could Make Sports Betting Legal Across the Country";
                titleNoFormatting = "New Jersey Lawsuit Could Make Sports Betting Legal Across the Country";
                unescapedUrl = "http://lawnewz.com/sports/new-jersey-lawsuit-could-make-sports-betting-legal-across-the-country/";
                url = "http%3A%2F%2Flawnewz.com%2Fsports%2Fnew-jersey-lawsuit-could-make-sports-betting-legal-across-the-country%2F";
            }
        );
    };
    responseDetails = "";
    responseStatus = 200;
}
```

I'm really confused by this because it doesn't look like most examples I've seen online.

Comment: Parse `results` into custom objects. Keep data as JSON the least possible time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add SwiftyJSON from github and do the stuff below

```
     import SwiftyJSON

      func parseJson() {

        Alamofire.request(.POST, "urlString", parameters:   parameter, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in


            //Check Response

            if response.result.isFailure == true {
                return
            }

            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)

          let cursorEntity = json["Cursor"]
          let currentIndex = json["cursor"].currentPageIndex
          let pageEntity =  json["cursor"]["pages"]
          let resultsEntity = json["cursor"]["results"]
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I played around some more and ended up getting SwiftJSON and used your method. It works great now!

Answer (score 0):

Use Alamofire with [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) plugin called [Alamofire-SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON)

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, 
  urlString, 
  parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
.responseSwiftyJSON({ (request, response, json, error) in
  var cursor = json["cursor"]
  // do your stuff ..
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As @cem olcay mentioned above use the Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. Try the below code. But haven't tested.

```
func getData() {
Alamofire.request(.GET, "YOUR_URL_STRING")
         .responseJSON { response in


let json = JSON(data: response)
if let title = json[0]["relatedStories"][0]["title"].string {
  //Now you got your value
}

         }
}
```