# Parsing JSON using the new Swift 3 and Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift3

I'm using Alamofire as HTTP library, since the update to Swift 3, how do you parse JSON based on the example below?

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)

    if let json = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(json)")
    }
}
```

`respone.result.value` is of Any object, and is very new and confusing.

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35447161/need-help-parsing-json-with-swift-using-alamofire?rq=1 ?

Comment: @MartinDelille it is the same but I think it is still using the Swift 2, there are a lot of breaking changes and SwiftyJSOn has not yet been upgrade to latest Swift 3

Comment: @LawGimenez See update for using SwiftyJSON with Swift 3.

Comment: Did you really have to put "Swift 3" twice in the title?

Comment: @LeoNatan I'm sorry I was in a hurry with deadlines and all, no idea this was such a big deal in StackOverflow. It won't happen again in the future I promise. Just came back here and edited the title so you can sleep peacefully and all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you can see in [Alamofire tests](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Tests/RequestTests.swift) you should cast `response.result.value` to `[String:Any]`:

```
if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at this, will accept this answer once I confirmed it.

Comment: Yes I have tried adding that Pod and not yet working, I have a lot of compile errors as of yesterday.

Comment: Have you updated your app to Swift 3? Nevertheless my answer should work for you.

Comment: Yes updated to Swift 3 yesterday, and your solution worked also. Also, found out that you could do if let json = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {}

Comment: Do you have a non-swiftyJson example?

Comment: @MicroR No, the question was about SwiftyJSON.

Comment: Hmm I see nothing in the question saying "SwiftyJson".

Comment: @MicroR Yep, sorry :) You can get parsed json tree by `response.result.value as? [String: Any]` and you do not need SwiftyJSON for that.

Comment: I removed SwiftyJSON part of my answer so it does not confuse anyone.

Answer (score 3):

> Updated for swift 3 :

if your response is like below,

```
[
    {
        "uId": 1156,
        "firstName": "Kunal",
        "lastName": "jadhav",
        "email": "kunal@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "7612345631",
        "subuserid": 4,
        "balance": 0
    }
]
```

**if you want to parsing the above JSON response used below simple lines of code: **

```
    Alamofire.request(yourURLString, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)

            if let data = response.result.value{

                if  (data as? [[String : AnyObject]]) != nil{

                    if let dictionaryArray = data as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>> {
                        if dictionaryArray.count > 0 {

                            for i in 0..<dictionaryArray.count{

                                let Object = dictionaryArray[i]
                                if let email = Object["email"] as? String{
                                    print("Email: \(email)")
                                }
                                if let uId = Object["uId"] as? Int{
                                    print("User Id: \(uId)")
                                }
                                // like that you can do for remaining...
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                let error = (response.result.value  as? [[String : AnyObject]])
                print(error as Any)
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use SwiftyJson do this with Alamofire 4.0:

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseString { response in
    debugPrint(response)

    if let json = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(json)")
    }
}
```

The key point being use `responseString` instead of `responseJSON`.

Source: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-string-handler

Comment: You do not need SwiftyJSON to use `responseJSON`.

Comment: @mixel yeah I know. The `responseJSON` was giving me issues in swift 3 + alamofire 4.0 though when I updated my app. Changing it to `responseString` helped me solve the issue without having to change anything else.