# Alamofire json request Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I have the following JSON structure

```
{"id":"941","title":"dsadadadadsad","description":"dsadadadsadad","added":"2017-01-10 19:00:47"}
```

Now I'm trying to make a request and output the data, but I can't access the json property: `object.description`

I'm trying this and doesn't work

```
    Alamofire.request("http://localhost:8080/foo.php").responseJSON{ response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print(JSON["description"])
        }
    }
```

It doesn't build. How can I output the value of `"description"`?

//LE error
[image]

Comment: "It doesn't build" What do you mean? Can you post error message?

Comment: @AhmetA. Done! I've added an image

Comment: Try This   
var  description : String = JSON.object(forKey : "description
") as! String
print(description)

Comment: `if let data = response.result.value as? [String:String] {
            print(data["description"])
        }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468516/parsing-json-using-the-new-swift-3-and-alamofire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unwrap value like this :

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
            //deal with JSON["description"
}
```

You can also unwrap this like [String:String] if your JSON contains only String values