# Alamofire receive and parse an array of strings swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I getting the result as an array of strings like this

```
["India","America","Australia","China","Russia"]
```

And I'm using **Alamofire** to get the response using code. There's no error, but I got the result as null. Please help in parsing this.

```
sessionManager?.request(strURL, method: method, parameters: params, encoding: encoding , headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
   switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let resJson = JSON(response.result.value!)
           success(resJson)
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            failure(error as NSError)
            break
        }

    }
```

Comment: are you added the transportsecurity in your .plist

Comment: Yes....I'm using allow arbitrary loads

Comment: then access like `let resJson = response.result.value as [String]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON using the new Swift 3 and Alamofire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468516/parsing-json-using-the-new-swift-3-and-alamofire)

Comment: let resJson = response.result.value as [String] 
Thanks @Anbu.Karthik ....It worked well

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if let responseData = response.result.value{    
let responsevalue = responseData  as? [String]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for another derived answer, just put this chunk of code after `Alamofire.request(...)`:

```
.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in

            switch response.result{

            case .success(let value):

                // Here is your array of String
                let arrayOfStrings = value as? [String]

            case .failure(let error):

                // Some code when error happens...
                print(error.localizedDescription)

            }

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution using SwiftyJSON:

```
.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in

     switch response.result{
     case .failure(let error):
         print(error.localizedDescription)

     case .success(let res):
       let json = JSON(res)
       let res = json["result"]

       var models = [String]()
       if let models1 = company["models"].array {
           for model in models1 {
               guard let mod = model.string else { return }
               models.append(mod)
           }
       }
     }
})
```